# PHP Why does explicit typecast + 1 work, but not with an increment operator

Tags: php, casting

Firstly, let's say for the sake of argument, the reasons why I want to do this is arbitrary and not solution specific.

I would like to explicitly cast a variable, regardless of input, and increment it *after* typecasting, *not* with the original variable. For example, not like this:

```
$num = "47 downvotes";
(int) ++$num;
```

I am looking for something similar to this psuedo-coded version, or a variation thereof:

```
$num = "value";
++((int) $num);
```

For PHP being loose, I was really hoping this to work, but I can't use the Pre-increment operator without creating another variable first.

```
$num = "value";
$cast = (int) $num;
echo ++$cast;
```

While testing, I found that PHP is *loose enough* for it to work by adding a digit however:

```
$num = "47 dogs";
echo ((int) $num) + 1;
```

I also understand my first example, isn't wrong, but again, for arbitrary reasons, I need to make sure it has been casted prior to incrementing/decrementing.

So the question is, why is PHP loose enough for the latter to compile?

If you could provide resources or links to any reputable reading material I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: I think of it this way: Results of function calls or - in your case - casts are stored in a read-only anonymous variable. You can use it as long as you only read from it. You can pass it to a function, or add 1 and then print it. But you can't pass it by reference, and you can't pre-/post-increment it, because that requires writing to said anon variable.

Comment: ah, you make a good point about references. I do understand that it's anonymous, and read-only it may be, but I wouldnt say that I'm writing to it right? I'm simply using it's *value* for an arithmetic expression. So for example, `echo "42" + 2`, I'm not writing to "42", anonymous or not, it still maintains that value. Same thing for `$result = ((int) $num) + 1`. or `$result = ((int) $num)++` (int) $num maintains its value, even if I pass it as reference, which I think is why we have explicit casting. Another point I made below, if you use `gettype((int) $num)` it identifies as integer @jh1711

Comment: I'd would say that with '`++`' you do write to it. If you take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) `++$a` means increments $a by one (**and stores the result in $a**), and returns $a (I added the boldded).  If you run `$a = 42; echo $a + 1, $a + 1, ++$a, ++$a, $a;` you'll see that the first two calculation don't change $a, but the third and the fourth do, and still use its value.

Comment: I'm not sure what your argument with gettype is. It takes its argument by value. But e.g. `settype((int) $a, 'int');` is not only redundant, but it throws a fatal error, because you can't reference `(int) $a`.

Comment: I see. Solid points @jh1711 Cleared up a lot of things there. I think that's why `settype()` and `intval()` won't work, because they do require you pass by reference. I can see now that, its not really a matter of what it is, because it's loose, just a matter if it's a var with an allocated address. And an explicit cast does not have one. In fact, you can't inc/dec anything inline: `echo "42"++` or `echo 42++`. I guess I should have known this, since PHP inc/dec is C-friendly. And in C you get lvalue errors when trying to reference an object that doesn't occupy identifiable location in memory

Comment: And people say they hate PHP because it's *too* loose! pshhh.

Comment: @jh1711 if you care to write an answer, I’d gladly accept it as I think your reasonings directly answer the question at hand of why +1 works, but not `(..)++` as opposed to the given answers. If not, no worries, thanks for a positive discussion.

Comment: soulshined, I don't want to post an answer. I think we had a very positive back and fourth, but I still can't find a concise way to define all things you can or can't increment, let alone why or why not.  But  in certain edge cases even the PHP developers don't agree, as we can in this SPL example https://3v4l.org/cNV9B, where the behavior changed from 7.1.7 to 7.1.8. I think its best we leave the issue as it is. Maybe somebody else has an answer with additional insight.

Answer (score 0):

With explicit typecasting you have to assign the result to a variable.  In your examples, you are trying to increment variables when they are strings, which fails or doesn't produce the result you expect in combination with typecasting.

Look at your original example:

```
<?php

$num = "47 downvotes";
echo $num . PHP_EOL;
echo ++$num;
```

The result of incrementing a string isn't what you expect it to be:

```
47 downvotes
47 downvotet
```

So your original supposition is that PHP doesn't work when in fact it does.

```
$num = "47 downvotes";
echo (int) ++$num . PHP_EOL;

$num2 = "47";
echo (int) ++$num2;
```

Output:

```
47
48
```

The process of typecasting is inherently complicated, and has all sorts of behavior that can produce unexpected results, and just isn't the catchall dependable "fix your input" that will let you find the numeric portion of any string available to you in a single line of code, but that doesn't mean that PHP is flawed.

Comment: I agree and in hindsight I shouldnt have used that example because I knew it would sway answers, but thats one of the reasons why I need to inc/dec after the cast. Regardless it still doesnt answer why ++ wont work with an explicit cast but +1 does. If you were to use `gettype((int) $num)`, even being anonymous, it still identifies as integer, and order of operations tells me parenthesis comes first, so I dont understand why ++ wont work. And if your answer is *With explicit typecasting you have to assign the result to a variable* do you mind elaborating and correlating that to the question?

Comment: I added another example to address your point as I understand it.